# Debugging CodeIgniter with FirePHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebug

I'm using CodeIgniter with WAMP (PHP 5.3.8) on Windows 7 and using Firebug and everything is fine, except I've decided to use FirePHP and it's not working.

Here's what I'm doing:
I have Firefox 35.0.1, Firebug 2.0.7 and FirePHP 0.7.4.
I've downloaded FirePHPCore 0.3.2 and copied the files 'fb.php' and 'FirePHP.class.php' to the libraries folder. I've autoloaded `fb` and then I've gone to the controller and entered `$this->fb->log('TEST');`.

The word `TEST` does not appear in the console.
Have I got a compatibility problem or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you don't just try

```
$this->firephp->log($sql);
```

Comment: I have and codeigniter throws an error 'An error was encountered' - very helpful!

Comment: Don't use fb.php just Firephp.php and use $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','firephp');
$this->firephp->log($this->db->last_query($sql));

Comment: Yes it works! So straightforward. Thank you so much for solving the problem. Why in the world are there so many pages giving the wrong advice?